# Date comparison with System Date in R

Tags: r, date, compare

I want to compare the data from one column which is the end date(end_date) with the system date(todays_date). Both columns are in the char format.

```
Input:
$ name: chr  "Abby" "Abby" "Abby" "Abby" ...
$ std: int  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
$ end_date: chr  "25-02-2016" "25-02-2016" "25-03-2018" "25-02-2019" ...
$ todays_date: chr  "07-03-2018" "07-03-2018" "07-03-2018" "07-03-2018" ...
```

Is there any way I can pass a `sqldf` statement where I can get all the values of the input csv where end_date < todays_date? Any way other than a `sqldf` statement where I can extract the values of the csv where end_date< todays_date will do.

I tried a few possible variations the below query but I can't seem to get the required output:

```
sel_a <- sqldf(paste("SELECT * FROM input_a WHERE end_date<", 
todays_date, "", sep = ""))
sel_a
```

PS: I have a huge amount of data and have reduced it to fit this question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a more specific answer, make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Convert the date column from character to date-time objects, e.g., with

```
library(lubridate)
your_df$end_date <- mdy(your_df$end_date)
```

Then, you don't even need a column for todays date, just use it as a filter condition

```
library(dplyr)
filter(your_df, end_date < Sys.Date())
# will return a data frame with those rows that have a date before today.
```

Or if you prefer:

```
your_df[your_df$end_date < Sys.Date(),]
# produces the same rows
```

Comment: I converted end_date using as.Date and then used your_df[your_df$end_date < Sys.Date(),] . It works. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using the raw input shown in the Note at the end first convert the dates to `"Date"` class and then use any of the alternatives shown.  The first two use `end_date` in the input and the last two use `Sys.Date()`.  We show both `sqldf` and base solutions.

```
library(sqldf)
fmt <- "%d-%m-%Y"
Input <- transform(Input_raw, end_date = as.Date(end_date, fmt),
                              todays_date = as.Date(todays_date, fmt))

# 1
sqldf("select * from Input where end_date <= todays_date")

# 2
subset(Input, end_date <= todays_date)

# 3
fn$sqldf("select * from Input where end_date <= `Sys.Date()`")

# 4
subset(Input, end_date <= Sys.Date())
```

### Note

The `Input` in reproducible form:

```
Input_raw <- data.frame(name = "Abby", std = 2:5, 
  end_date = c("25-02-2016", "25-02-2016", "25-03-2018", "25-02-2019"),
  todays_date = "07-03-2018", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```